# Using tuples instead of boolean operators

Tags: python, tuples, boolean-operations

Is there a difference (in terms of performance, not readability) between the following ways of evaluating two (or more) conditions linked by `and`?

```
a == 1 and b == 2
```

or

```
(a,b) == (1,2)
```

The same for `or`:

```
a == 1 or b == 1
```

or

```
1 in (a,b)
```

Which way is preferable? The one using boolean operators or the other one using tuples?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using and/or operators are almost always better in terms of performance (perhaps not for readability but that's another issue):
1. They avoid having to create tuple objects like you do in other examples which will be more costly in terms of space/time complexity
2. They short-circuit meaning there is a good chance you can avoid executing unnecessary portions of the code.

Answer (score 4):

These are some timings using `python 2.7`

```
In [29]: a = 1 

In [30]: b = 2

In [31]: timeit a == 1 and b == 2
10000000 loops, best of 3: 82.2 ns per loop

In [32]: timeit (a,b) == (1,2)
10000000 loops, best of 3: 132 ns per loop

In [33]: timeit 1 in (a,b)
10000000 loops, best of 3: 118 ns per loop
```

And when the outcome is False:

```
In [37]: timeit a == 2 and b == 2
10000000 loops, best of 3: 52.2 ns per loop

In [38]: timeit 3 in (a,b)
10000000 loops, best of 3: 151 ns per loop

In [39]: timeit (a,b) == (2,2)
10000000 loops, best of 3: 144 ns per loop
```

`a == 2 and b == 2` is faster as `and` is a [short circuit operator](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#boolean-operations-and-or-not)

As per wim's comment using a set will be faster than checking the tuple for membership:

```
In [55]: timeit 3 in {a,b}
10000000 loops, best of 3: 92.9 ns per loop
```

Comment: if you use a set literal like `3 in {a,b}` you will likely see better performance than with a tuple

Answer (score 3):

Yes, there is a logical difference in that that using `and`/`or` are short-circuiting.

```
>>> def return1():
...     return 1
... 
>>> def raises():
...     raise Exception('uh oh')
... 
>>> a, b = 1, 2
>>> a == return1() or b == raises()
True
>>> b == return1() and a == raises()
False
```

Note the function which raises exception never gets called.  In both the other examples, we will have an unhandled exception:

```
>>> a, b == return1(), raises()
# raises Exception
>>> 1 in (return1(), raises())
# raises Exception ..
```

In the case of literals, this obviously doesn't make any difference to the flow and any performance differences are likely to be negligible.  I prefer the second style in this case.

Comment: Good point mentioning comparisons with the return value of a function! Thanks!